# highchats in r shiny: the x values on click are not the real values of my date axis

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

My x-axis is date and on click, I want to get it but what I am getting is a very large number. Do I have to perform some conversion?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(highcharter)
data("economics_long", package = "ggplot2")


ui <- fluidPage(

           highchartOutput('my_plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$my_plot <- renderHighchart({
        
         canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.x]);}")
        hchart(economics_long,'line',  hcaes(date, value01, group = variable)) %>%  hc_legend(
            align = "right",
            verticalAlign = "top",
            layout = "vertical"
        ) %>% hc_plotOptions(
            series = list(
                cursor = "pointer",
                point = list(
                    events = list(
                        click = canvasClickFunction 
                    ))))
        
    })
  
    
  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
        print(input$canvasClicked)
    })
    

    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time that you get is in milliseconds. Convert it to seconds and use `as.POSIXct` to get actual date-time.

```
 observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
   print(as.POSIXct(input$canvasClicked/1000, origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC'))
 })
```